# The constructor URL(Elements) is undefined

Tags: url, jsoup

i m using  **jsoup** Application and trying to get url of web pages. i got  urls of web page. i m trying to get only image urls via **url parsing** 
but when sending request to url i got this error 
**" The constructor URL(Elements) is undefined "**

my question is how can i pass urls that i got from jsoup library
here is my code 
' public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

```
    Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
    String url = args[0];
    print("Fetching %s...", url);
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
    Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");
```

'
and using

```
'Elements imagepath = doc.select("[src]");'
```

and passing this Lement into url parsing function

```
URL url = new URL(imagepath);
```

can anyone help me to figure it out how to get url parsing function works 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get that exception is because you pass `Elements` to the `URL` constructor - the `Elements` is just the specialization of `List<Element>`. This means you probably have more than one image assigned to `imagepath` variable. If you would like to construct the `URL` objects from the scraped images, consider this code sample:

```
Elements images = document.select("img");
for (Element element : images) {
    System.out.println(element.attr("abs:src"));
}
```

This should help you making progress with your application. I would love to answer any further question you might have.

Comment: i used yout code but it did not works. in imagepath veriable , i m sending to store list of url that i got from jsoup librabry and after that url will check for image urls an after that i image will donwload

Comment: it works but i m getting default url : http://www.amrood.com/index.htm?language=en#j2se can u please tell me how i can store list of urls in imanepath veriable to do further computation

Comment: If you would like to get the images from the website, you should probably limit your selector to `img` elements and then in the loop you can select all absolute urls with `abs:src` selector. I've edited my answer so it contains an improved code example.

Comment: sorry for late reply i delete the code that getting addition information like script location and links locations and used your above code and after run i got Error " document cannot be resolved" ,Please help me waiting for reply....